# Interpret R output Rpart classification tree surrogate splits

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, rpart

```
Surrogate splits:
    ##       bmi    < 21.51 to the right, agree=0.858, adj=0.632, (0 split)
```

I understand that this split send cases to the right child node based on a bmi value of < 21.51 and has a similar split to the primary variable (agree = 0.858) and a decent decrease in node impurity (adj=0.632).

I do not understand the (0 split) piece of the output?
Also, if agreement had a value of 1, would this be suspicious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you have for example 10 missing in your first primary split then rpart will try to classify them using the surrogate splits. 
If 9 of these are non-missing in your first surrogate variable rpart will use this variable and you will have **(9 split)** in your rpart output next to this surrogate variable since the variable was used for 9 splits.

If your data is also missing for your surrogate variables then you will have **(0 splits)** in your output.

I do not know the exact calculation of **agreement** but if you would have an agreement of **1** then I guess that the surrogate variable results in the same classification as when using the primary variable.
This could happen if your surrogate variable is, for example, a monotone transformed version of the primary variable.